# Install mongosh on Ubuntu Jammy 22.04 without libssl1.1

Tags: command-line, 22.04, mongodb

If you're using Atlas and want to connect to your cluster from your terminal

```
wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-mongosh_1.9.0_amd64.deb
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-mongosh_1.9.0_amd64.deb
```

Finally:

```
mongosh "mongodb+srv://<YOUR_CLUSTER_ID>" --apiVersion 1 --username <DB_USERNAME>
```

You will then be prompted with your username password

Source: [The mongo atlas modal when requesting connection via shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQwmC.png)

Apparently even though in their documentation they mention supporting Jammy. They haven't taken into consideration the libssl1.1 issue. Or at least I wasn't able to find any awareness regarding that.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  What is the problem, exactly? What are you trying to do?